# How to launch ./a.out in new terminal window?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, terminal

I want to make a C++ program to clear the screen again and again and write to terminal. How can I achieve to launch my program in new terminal window from the main terminal?

Comment: How about using a library such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)?

Comment: That depends on your terminal, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options depending on your terminal. Here is a pretty comprehensive article on the matter:

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/